# Self-correcting beacons is it possible to work?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I read a paper discussing about a method to reduce beacon's measurement  error up to 10%.
I was wondering if it's possible. Basically the self-correcting beacon system is composed of two beacons: target beacon and self-correcting beacon. These two beacons are positioned one meter far from the other.The measuring device (the device we want to calculate the distance from) is positioned at `d` meters far from the target beacon. Basically the target beacon broadcasts a message, self-correcting beacon will get, calculate the RSSI save as srcPower (RSSI at 1m distance) and broadcasts again. On the other hand, the target device will get the message from target beacon that was sent in the beginning and a message from the self-correcting beacon. So the measuring device uses this "more recent RSSI(d0) (srcPower) to calculate the distance"... does anybody tried to implement and it worked?

The link to the scientific paper is this one:

https://www.ronpub.com/OJIOT_2015v1i2n03_Cho.pdf

Comment: Interesting idea.  It is essentially doing a constant calibration automatically in near real time.  I suspect it would not perform much better than a proper one-tine  calibration each time the beacon is moved or the environment altered.  But many people do not do a proper calibration when needed.

Comment: right, a real time calibrating system. I will do some tests like they did to check the results just as curiosity if it gets lower than normal one would be incredible but beacons rssi are so random that it might be the same with or without real time calibrating system, dont you think so? I made a new topic asking how to obtain data because it will help me to do tests, could you check please?